# Add custom button on add/edit product page

Tags: php, xml, layout, magento2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHZ33.png

How to add a custom button, in add/edit product page (magento2). I need to open popup on clicking of the button.

Answer (score 1):

The product form is generated via **ui-components**.
The ui component name for product form is `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`.

You need to create a file with the same name and path in your own module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="button-unique-identifier-here" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Then create the class `[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton` in the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/CustomButton.php`

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

class CustomButton extends Generic
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Your button label here'),
            'on_click' => "alert('it works')",
            'sort_order' => 100
        ];
    }
}
```

Your ui component file should be merged with the main file and your buttons should appear among the other buttons.

**Check these changes after cache flush**