# How to create in Magento 2 a custom button with dropdown on product edit page?

Tags: php, magento2

I need to create a custom button on a product edit page.

This button should be the same as [the add product button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hyoB.png), but with custom name and custom links in a dropdown menu. For example, one of links should open my custom module config page).

I can't find any documentation or tutorial for this. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657067/add-custom-button-on-add-edit-product-page) I know how to make simple custom button, but I can't find any info about how to create the button with dropdown with my own links.

I would be grateful for any information regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this maybe help you

[create-split-button-list-in-admin-panel-magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/create-split-button-list-in-admin-panel-magento2/)